# Select in XML to a list

Tags: c#, xml, list, select

I just want to select the content of  `user list="default"`  or `user list="otherListName"` from a variable. 
Like when my variable is equal to `default` I want to select the content of `user list="default"`. By content I mean:

```
<list nom="Nom" description="Description" image="no_image.png"/>
```

And I want this content to be parse into a list

```
<list nom="" description="" image=""/>
<list nom="" description="" image=""/>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<database>
    <user list="default">
        <list nom="Nom" description="Description" image="no_image.png"/>
    </user>
    <user list="otherListName">
        <list nom="" description="" image=""/>
        <list nom="" description="" image=""/>
    </user>
</database>`
```

I hope that my question is understandable.

Comment: Take a look at this working example to see how to use linq to pull data from Xml and create a list.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/FkyqvA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ-to-XML, for example, assuming that `doc` is an [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) variable containing the original XML :

```
var listName = "default";
var result = doc.Root
                .Elements("user")
                .Where(o => (string)o.Attribute("list") == listName)
                .Elements("list");
```

**See live demo in [`dotnetfiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hhlQAv) :**

```
var raw = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<database>
    <user list='default'>
        <list nom='Nom' description='Description' image='no_image.png'/>
    </user>
    <user list='otherListName'>
        <list nom='' description='' image=''/>
        <list nom='' description='' image=''/>
    </user>
</database>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(raw);

var listName = "default";
var result = doc.Root
                .Elements("user")
                .Where(o => (string)o.Attribute("list") == listName)
                .Elements("list");

foreach(var r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.ToString());
}
```

**output :** (for `listName = "default"`)

```
<list nom="Nom" description="Description" image="no_image.png" />
```